# Why i am getting error of wrong no of arguments in link_to rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am working on app of Rails 4.2 and facing an unusual issue as below.

```
**ERROR**
wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)
```

on link_to with syntax

```
<%= link_to 'In Progress', letters_path(status_filter: 'In Progress') %>
```

Please find attached screenshot for reference. This seems very much strange to me as I am not able to find any issue with code.

[image]

**Routes**

[image]

**FULL TRACE**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide the routing definition for the letters resource

Comment: [SimoneCarletti](http://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti) Please find attached routes

Comment: some stack trace as well

Comment: [Nithin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2231236/nithin) Full Trace added. Please review

Comment: Remove temporary `bartt-ssl_requirement` in Gemfile and try again. May be that's why `link_to` is not working normally.

Comment: Or try to upgrade `bartt-ssl_requirement` to last stable version.

Comment: You are welcome, I don't know this gem more than you, may be some configuration necessary fix your problem.

Comment: I need that gem so i am working on alternative of it

Comment: @Jeet Probably this discussion is relevant to your issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25007

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need bartt-ssl_requirement gem, like 孙悟空 said: try to take it away to check if that's the cause of the problem - It's on the top of the stack trace.

As said on the readme `bartt-ssl_requirement is compatible with ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.x.`

Did you recently upgraded your app to rails 4?

Comment: Yes, And i think link provided by [dp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4002659/dp7) will help